# authorship with NLTK using Python on my own Corpus

Tags: nltk

I'm trying to implement Authorship identification using NLTK, so far, I couldn't figure it out how should I arrange the corpus, and assuming the easiest scenario of using BOW as the feature, I don't know how to store this feature, like list, set, FreqDist, or Dic? What I would like to do is having my docs in folders, each folder is the class label, like author1 as a folder and all his training docs inside that folder, and so does the other authors.what I have played so far is making all the documents for one auther as one big text file saved on the gutenberg corpus and moved original gutenberg files and using:

from nltk.corpus import gutenberg

By this I do access my files and can do the BOW but don't know how to store them to be sent to  classification.
I have tried to modify the movie_reviews following example to fit my corpus but failed:

```
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=200)),
                     ('nb', MultinomialNB())])
classif = SklearnClassifier(pipeline)

from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
pos = [FreqDist(movie_reviews.words(i)) for i in movie_reviews.fileids('pos')]
neg = [FreqDist(movie_reviews.words(i)) for i in movie_reviews.fileids('neg')]
add_label = lambda lst, lab: [(x, lab) for x in lst]
classif.train(add_label(pos[:100], 'pos') + add_label(neg[:100], 'neg'))

l_pos = np.array(classif.batch_classify(pos[100:]))
l_neg = np.array(classif.batch_classify(neg[100:]))
print "Confusion matrix:\n%d\t%d\n%d\t%d" % (
          (l_pos == 'pos').sum(), (l_pos == 'neg').sum(),
          (l_neg == 'pos').sum(), (l_neg == 'neg').sum())
```

Any help will be much appreciated, if any can collaborate on which is better like to have files in folders for each author or one big text file for each author

Thanks